# Can we mount a container directory on the host?

Tags: docker

Let's say we have some data on a container

```
RUN mkdir resources
COPY resources/*.csv resources/
VOLUME resources
```

This can be mounted in another container through `docker-compose`, but is there a way to bind that directory to an empty host directory? That is, I want to do exactly the opposite that is done with the `-v` flag.

*Note* a workaround would be to copy that directory to a mounted volume at startup, I guess, but I'd like to know if there's some way to do it that's more idiomatic.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve? Since the volume is already mounted inside the container, it cannot be 'bound' to the host at the same time, you'll get the `device or resource is busy` error.

Comment: All the volumes you create, by default live in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` as directories on the host. You can access that directory directly if you want.

Comment: @zer0 Right, but it's got funny names... a long hash. Maybe what they correspond to can be found out via docker inspect?

Comment: I suppose so. You will be able to see the `source` parameter on the volume, which will have the exact path as value.

Comment: How is Docker involved with the process?  As you're describing it, the `resources` directory starts off on the host, and you're trying to access it from the host, so you should just be able to use `cp` to copy the files from one place to another.

Comment: @DavidMaze It's a different host.